# I'm looking for help to display a part on my database according to my previous choices in the select buttons

Tags: javascript, database, symfony, twig

i study the web developpement and i'm actually stuck with a problem.

I have two select buttons in which my database is displayed, the concern being that I would like the second select button to display only the results based on the first one. A bit like if the first button select would have inside "Numbers" and "Letters" and the second in consequences would have inside "1" "2" "3" if in the first select button we choose "Numbers" and "a" "b" "c" if we choose "Letters". I currently only have the full display of my entire database in the second and it does not do the sorting.

I tried a lot of thing but not realy working this is why i come here to have some help or tips.

I'm currently working with symfony 3.4 and on ubuntu.

Here is the code for my first select button:

```
<select id="sel1" class="formDevis" >
                            <option> Cliquez pour choisir </option>
                        {% for categorie in categories %}
                            <option>{{ categorie.nomCategories }} 
                            </option>
                        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then this is the code for the second select button:

```
<select id="prod1" class="formDevis">
                            <option> Cliquez pour choisir </option>
                            <option>Non spécifié</option>
                            {% for produit in produits %}
                                <option>{{ produit.nomProduits }} 
                                </option>
                            {% endfor %}
</select>
```

And finaly here is the code i use in my controller:

```
/**
     * Lists all devis entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="admin_devis_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $devis = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Devis')->findAll();
        $produits = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Produits')->findAll();
        $categories = $em->getRepository('DevisBundle:Categories')->findAll();


        return $this->render('categories/devis.html.twig', array(
            'produits' => $produits,
            'devis' => $devis,
            'categories' => $categories
        ));
    }
```

I tried to have on the second button select the display of my database according to the first button select but I managed to have the complete display.

Comment: You already asked this and never gived a feedback to who helped you giving an answer

Comment: Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633474/im-looking-for-help-to-display-a-part-of-my-database-according-to-my-previous-c) your previous question (with new information/attempts) instead of reasking the same question again. Editing a question will give it renewed attention

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use AJAX in your twig view like this :

```
   //event on change of the first select

        $('#firstSelect').change(function(){

                    // Url to the controller where you do some action and return the second 
                    //list depend of select on the first select
                    var url = "{{path('route_to_a_controller_that_handle_your_request')}}";

                // With this Jquery selector you get the select value on the first select
                var data  ={"id" : $('#select option:selected').val()};

                $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data : data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Empty the second select
                        // For each element in response, do something like :
                        // $('#SecondSelect').append('<option value="1">One</option>');
                    }
});
```

And the controller to return the response (that's what you get in the 'success' of the AJAX). This is the controller your route refer in the ajax method.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
public function myMethodAction(Request $request)
{
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
        {
          $id_list1 = $request->get('id');
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $data = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:List2')->findByType($id_list1);

          return new JsonResponse($data);
      }
      return new Response("Error");
    }
```

I hope it will help, I realise this very quickly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the anwser, actually i'm learning as i said and i don't understand what i am supposed to put in the code you wrote at
``` var data  ={"id" : $('#select option:selected').val()}; ```  
  Sorry to be that newbie and thanks for helping